# plural nouns in sequences

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

When there are several plural nouns in a sequence, do they all take the plural form or does only the last noun take the plural e.g.,

> The application is a precious instrument full of information, advice**s**, curiositie**s** and suggestion**s**.

Comment: You do not use "pluralized" forms of count nouns; *advice* is usually used as a mass noun; *curiosity* is used as either a mass or count noun (look the word up in a good dictionary); so that leaves only *suggestions* as the only count noun in the sentence. But if you had multiple count nouns, you would pluralize them all: *This  bowl is full of delicious apples, oranges and dates.*

Answer (score 1):

The words "information" and "advice" cannot be pluralized. The words "curiosity" and "suggestion" can be pluralized but take on different meaning in plural than in singular.

So, no, the nouns do not have to be all singular or all plural.

Comment: In industry-specific terminology (across several industries), an "advice" means a "message of advisement."  Thus, it is proper in that context to refer to more than one of these messages as "advices".